# jQuery fancybox append image source to href

Tags: jquery, fancybox, append, href

I'm using fancybox plugin on my site. I want to use jQuery to detect the image source and place it in the href.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="img/sam_skirrow_the_moment_3.jpg" class="item_img"/>
</div>
```

and I'm using jquery to append the fancybox code:

```
   $('<a class="fancybox" href="[IMAGE SOURCE]"></a>').appendTo('.item');
```

What code do I need to grab the img src and add it in as the source for href?? Something like this perhaps?

```
$('<img>').attr('src').appendTo('.fancybox');
```

So my question is: how do I use jQuery to grab the src of an image and add it to the "href". i.e. a href="[SRC OF IMAGE]"

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: The problem here is, how do I use jQuery to grab the src of an image and add it to the "href". i.e. a href="[SRC OF IMAGE]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more than one `<img>` tag in your container (or not) like

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/1_b.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/2_b.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

etc. then you could use the `.each()` and the `.wrap()` methods like :

```
$(".item img").each(function () {
    var newHref = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).wrap("<a class='fancybox' rel='gallery' href='" + newHref + "'/>");
});
```

Of course, you still need to bind fancybox to the selector `.fancybox`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wfBTj/)**

Answer (score 1):

Select the image source before you initiate fancybox:

```
  var imgSrc = $('.item > img').attr('src');
  $('<a class="fancybox" href="'+imgSrc+'"></a>').appendTo('.item');
```

Comment: this almost worked, but when I click any of my images, fancybox just displays the first image. see here. www.samskirrow.com/new

Comment: how are you initialising Fancybox? It looks as though you are creating a fancy box for each image?  http://fancybox.net/howto says you should init it by "$("a.item_img").fancybox();"

Comment: I was initializing just using the basic command: $('.fancybox').fancybox(); tried your method just now and it brings up the image in a new window

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try something like this

```
$('.fancybox').attr('href',$('.item_img').attr('src'));
```

you can check `.attr` API from [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be as follows:

```
$(".item").find("img").each( function() {
     $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("src"));
};
```

If this works for you, please mark it as the answer!